# Deploying Two MVC 3 Apps in the same domain iis7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have a MVC 3 site that runs at the top level of a domain. I have just created a directory in this domain "Support" added another MVC 3 project to it and converted it to a application in IIS7.

The issue is that my parent MVC 3 application seems to be handling the routing still and when I hit the route http://mywebsite.com/Support/Account/etc I  get a 404 as this route doesn't exist in the parent site I am assuming? Is their a way to stop the parent site attempting to handle the route http://mywebsite.com/Support/ "Support" being the route I have another application in???

Comment: Route "http://localhost:82/Support" seems to resolve but routes below "support" return 404 http://localhost:82/Errors/Error?aspxerrorpath=/Support/Account/LogOn. The route "http://localhost:82/Errors/Error" is within the parent site. Custom 404 page

Comment: Essential it seems like the parent site is returning 404 because these route do not exist within it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you made the folder an application?  Are you making that folder the root of your app?  ie, is there a web.config file there, global.asax, etc..?

Comment: Yes the sub folder application has a global and web.config file. It works fine when I delete the parent site but when the parent site exists it seems to take control over the routing of the sub directory application

Comment: Yes I have made the folder a application.